# How to add new fields to Mobirise's form?

Tags: code-blocks

I'm using drag and drop website builder Mobirise and it's free template Mobirise 3 theme. I'm making a party site, so I need to add extra fields to its form, as it has only 4 fields. Do you know if it's possible to add 3 extra fields for example? As I understand it's impossible to do it in the application, so I would like to do it by myself. Or maybe you could recommend some free application for forms creation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the process of work with bootstrap builder Mobirise. But I guess that it's impossible to change the number of fields as the form wouldn't work in this case.
As far as I know, not very long time ago Mobirise launched a new extension FormBuilder.You can check it here: https://mobirise.com/extensions/form-builder/